# Squid3 Caching websites works but not for large files despite max size 6GB

Tags: linux, centos, proxy, ftp, squid

For a homelab environment, I setup a Squid 3.3.8 Caching server on CentOS 7 (minimal) as a proxy server (not as the default gateway with transparent caching).

With a Xubuntu client, I setup proxy networking with:

```
export http_proxy="192.168.1.15:3128"   (the same pattern for https and ftp)
```

Web browsing works and I can see it hit the log `/var/log/squid/access.log`.  However, big files like .ISO images are not being cached despite 30GB of cache space available and a 6GB per object size limit.

**How do I troubleshoot and fix this?**

I see two misses sequentially in the log files, which I understood means squid caching failed.

```
1442197979.371 394811 192.168.1.61 TCP_MISS/200 666894705 GET http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01.iso - HIER_DIRECT/140.211.166.134 application/octet-stream
----
1442199880.195 414232 192.168.1.61 TCP_MISS/200 666894705 GET http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01.iso - HIER_DIRECT/140.211.166.134 application/octet-stream
```

Squid Config:

```
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 30720 16 256
cache_mem 256 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
maximum_object_size 6 GB
cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
range_offset_limit -1
quick_abort_min -1 KB
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this answer here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/596982/100013)—and sourced from [this thread official Squid Proxy support site](http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-caching-larger-files-td4666004.html#a4666006)—the `maximum_object_size` should be placed above the `cache_dir` in the `squid.conf` file.

Knowing that, just change your configuration from this:

```
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 30720 16 256
cache_mem 256 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
maximum_object_size 6 GB
cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
range_offset_limit -1
quick_abort_min -1 KB
```

To this:

```
maximum_object_size 6 GB
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 30720 16 256
cache_mem 256 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
range_offset_limit -1
quick_abort_min -1 KB
```

Restart the Squid proxy and see what happens.